# shell script (with loop) to grep a list of strings one by one

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a big data text file (more than 100,000 rows) in this format:

```
0.000197239;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=CLCNKA;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc
0.00118343;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=CLCNKA;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.00276134;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=CLCNKA;GeneDetail.refGene=.;
0.0607495;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=CLCNKA;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.00670611;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=XDH;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.000197239;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=XDH;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.000394477;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=GRK4;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.0108481;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=GRK4;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.000394477;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=GRK4;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
0.0108481;AN=192;NS=2535;ANNOVAR_DATE=2015-12-14;Func.refGene=exonic;Gene.refGene=GRK4;GeneDetail.refGene=.;ExonicFunc.refGene=nonsynonymous_SNV;
```

Now, each row contains a gene name, such as in initial 4 rows there is `CLCNKA` gene. I am using `grep` command to count the frequency of each gene name in this data file, as:

```
grep -w "CLCNKA" my_data_file | wc -l
```

There are about 300 genes in a separate file which are to be searched in above data file. Can some expert please write a simple `shell script` with a loop to take gene name from a list one by one, and store its frequency in a separate file. So, the output file would be like this:

```
CLCNKA    4
XDH    2
GRK4    4
```

Comment: that's more a job for `awk`

Comment: So, can you please suggest the `awk` command for this, I edit the tag to `awk` also.

Comment: now that it's tagged properly, some awk expert will probably help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused us. I and some others think all you want is a count of each gene in the file since that's what your input/output and some of your descriptive text states (`count the frequency of each gene name in this data file`) which would just be this:

```
$ awk -F'[=;]' '{cnt[$11]++} END{for (gene in cnt) print gene, cnt[gene]}' file
GRK4 4
CLCNKA 4
XDH 2
```

while everyone else thinks you want a count of specific genes that exist in a different file since that's what your Subject line, proposed algorithm and the rest of your text states.

If everyone else is right then you'd need this tweak to read the "genes" file first and only count the genes in "file" that were listed in "genes":

```
awk -F'[=;]' 'NR==FNR{genes[$0]; next} $11 in genes{cnt[$11]++} END{for (gene in cnt) print gene, cnt[gene]}' genes file
GRK4 4
CLCNKA 4
XDH 2
```

Your example doesn't help since it would produce the same output with either interpretation of your requirements so edit your question to clarify what it is you want. In particular if there are genes that you do NOT want counted then include lines containing those in the sample input.

Comment: thanks for your concern dear. Yes the second case is true, I wanted to read the "genes" from a separate file, then search in the "data file" shown above and calculate the occurrence of genes. The output be a separate file as indicated above.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your friend

```
awk '{sub(/^.*Gene\.refGene=/,"");sub(/;.*$/,"");
     genelist[$0]++}END{for(i in genelist){print i,genelist[i]}}' file
```

**Output**

```
GRK4 4
CLCNKA 4
XDH 2
```

<sup>**Sidenote:** This may not give you the gene name frequency in the order in which they appear in the file. I guess that is not a requirement afterall.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in pure *bash*, by using the [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) feature to count the frequencies:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# declare assoc array
declare -A freq

# split stdin input csv
for gene in $(cut -d ';' -f 6|cut -d = -f 2);do
    let freq[$gene]++
done

# loop over array keys
for key in ${!freq[@]}; do
    echo ${key} ${freq[$key]}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution relying on the *uniq* command:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cut -d ';' -f 6|cut -d = -f 2|sort|uniq -c|while read -a kv;do
    echo  ${kv[1]} ${kv[0]}
done
```

Comment: No need for a loop and no need for 2 `cut`s: `awk -F'[;=]' '{print $11}' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'`. Not suggesting you should do that instead of 1 awk command of course

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-liner:

```
sed "s/.*Gene.refGene=//;s/\;.*//" test | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

`sed` - will remove everything from line except gene name
`sort` will do sorting by name
`uniq -c` - will count number of gene repeats
`awk` with swap uniq output (by default it : count pattern)

Answer (score 0):

To preserve order provided input file is sorted as given in sample:

```
$ perl -lne '
($g) = /Gene\.refGene=([^;]+)/;
if($g ne $p && $. > 1)
{
    print "$p\t$c";
    $c = 0;
}
$c++; $p = $g;
END { print "$p\t$c" }' ip.txt
CLCNKA  4
XDH     2
GRK4    4
```

If not, use hash variable to increment gene name used as key and an array to store key order

```
$ perl -lne '
($k) = /Gene\.refGene=([^;]+)/;
push(@o, $k) if !$h{$k}++;
END { print "$_\t$h{$_}" foreach (@o) }' ip.txt
CLCNKA  4
XDH     2
GRK4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only search for a list of genes, an inefficient but straightforward way

```
read g; do echo -n $g " "; grep -c $g file; done < genes
```

assuming your genes are listed one at a time in the genes file.

If your file structure is fixed, a more efficient version will be

```
awk 'NR==FNR{genes[$1];next} 
            {sub(/Gene.refGene=/,"",$6)} 
 $6 in genes{count[$6]++} 
         END{for(g in count) print g,count[g]}' genes FS=';' file
```